# embedding theorem in field theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $C$ be an algebraic closure of $E$.  Let $E/F$ be a finite separable extension of degree $n$, and let $\sigma$ be an embedding of $F$ into $C$. Then $\sigma $ extends to exactly $n$ embeddings of $E$ into $C$, in other words, there are exactly $n$ embeddings $\tau$ of $E$ in $C$ such that the restriction $\tau|_F$ of $\tau$ to $F$ coincides with $\sigma$, in particular, taking $\sigma$ to be the identity function on $F$, there are exactly $n$ $F-$monomorphism of $E$ into $C$.

Can anyone explain this theorem by using examples? I don understand what this theorem means.

Comment: Let's work out an example together. You could begin with the simplest case of all, take for $E=\mathbb{Q}$. What is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: The set which contains all algebraic numbers?

Comment: Actually, it is the *field* of algebraic numbers, which you constructed in the other thread. Now, let's take for $n=2$. What extension do you know with this degree?

Comment: Okay, I got the roles of $E$ and $F$ wrong. Let's take for $F = \mathbb{Q}$. An algebraic closure of $F$ is then an algebraic closure for every algebraic extension. Is $E|F$ necessarily algebraic?